# Coloring tail output with perl

Tags: sed, regular-expression, perl, tail, highlighting

```
tail -f logfile.log | perl -pe 's/.*foo*/\e[1;41m$&\e[0m/g'
```

will color all the lines containing the pattern "foo" in the logfile.log file.

How can I make use of this in order to highlight not the whole line but just the exact pattern?

```
echo "WARN ERROR foo"|sed 's#WARN#\x1b[33m&#; s#ERROR#\x1b[31m&#; s#foo#\x1b[32m&#'
```

I mean if I want to do something like this, how can I manage?

Comment: I don't understand, why aren't you just using the same regex for sed and perl?

Comment: what is the content of log file, and what output you expecting??

Comment: It's a live log file that is growing every seconds. And the server runs HPUX as OS. The only shell installed on it is ksh. What I need to search is depends but I need to highlight all the "Warning" words in "Green", all the "Error" words in "Red", all the "Bla" words in "Blue" like in the second example I gave but using the structure I used in first example.(I mean perl -pe) If there is any other way to do this highlighting in an old ksh lacking of most of the applications and properties of bash, I am open to all solutions.

Comment: What I need basically to get find out exactly what I search in a log quickly, and read them easily without losing time. And additionally to this, if there's a way get the copy of the logs and shape it in a human readable form It would be superb for me to learn about such a tool. ( I mean the paragraphs, new lines, line spaces, colors etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can use almost the exact same regular expression and syntax as you did with `sed`. Just change `&` to `$&` for Perl:

```
echo "WARN ERROR foo" | 
    perl -pe 's#WARN#\x1b[33m$&#; s#ERROR#\x1b[31m$&#; s#foo#\x1b[32m$&#'
```

Or, using your original Perl approach, just remove the `.*` on either side of the pattern you want to match:

```
tail -f logfile.log | perl -pe 's/foo/\e[1;41m$&\e[0m/g'
```

For a more versatile approach, you can use the little script I have posted in [my answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113553/22222). With it, you can color up to 10 patterns with a different color for each. For example, to color the words `ERROR`,`WARNING` and `foo`, in a different color, case-insensitively:

```
tail -f logfile.log | color.pl -il "error,warning,foo"
```

Comment: I'll try each and everymethodology provided. Just trying to speed up and develop my skills, looking for the cleanest and fastest way to get required information. Trying to gather my toolset. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that highlights from `ERROR` to the end of the line, the whole line containing `WARN`, and `foo` but nothing surrounding it. Only the first matching rule is applied (e.g. `WARN: ERROR foo` sets `ERROR foo` in red), tune as you see fit.

```
perl -pe 's/ERROR.*/\e[31m$&\e[0m/ || s/.*WARN.*/\e[33m$&\e[0m/ || s/foo/\e[32m$&\e[0m'
```

An alternative approach if you want to highlight keywords is to call a function to determine the color of the keyword. (This example doesn't do the same thing as the previous one: it always highlights the whole line.)

```
perl -pe '
    sub color {
         my ($keyword) = @_;
         $keyword =~ /err/i ? 31 :
         $keyword =~ /warn/i ? 33 :
         32;
    }
    if (/(ERROR|WARN|foo)/) {$color=color($1); s/^/\e[${color}m/; s/$/\e[0m/}
'
```

Comment: Why the `||`? Why not run all three on each line? You might have a line that matches both `ERROR` and `WARN`.

Comment: @terdon I was giving one example among the many possible desired behaviors. Well, ok, I went for the simpler example: if the patterns nest, you need to remember the active color, or merge them. Ignoring “WARN” on an “ERROR” line is probably the right thing anyway.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks a lot for the information provided. I'll come back in case of encountering new situations.