# How to use multiline as group-separator in grep?

Tags: shell, grep, quoting

In `grep` you can use `--group-separator` to write something in between group matches.

This comes handy to make it clear what blocks do we have, especially when using `-C X` option to get context lines.

```
$ cat a
hello
this is me
and this is
something else
hello hello
bye
i am done
$ grep -C1 --group-separator="+++++++++" 'hello' a
hello
this is me
+++++++++
something else
hello hello
bye
```

I learnt in [Using empty line as context "group-separator" for grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/113509/40596) how to just have an empty line, by saying `--group-separator=""`.

However, what if I want to have two empty lines? I tried saying `--group-separator="\n\n"` but I get literal `\n`s:

```
$ grep -C1 --group-separator="\n\n" 'hello' a
hello
this is me
\n\n
something else
hello hello
bye
```

Other things like `--group-separator="\nhello\n"` did not work either.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ooooh I found it, I just need to use the `$''` syntax instead of `$""`:

```
$ grep -C1 --group-separator=$'\n\n' 'hello' a
hello
this is me



something else
hello hello
bye
```

From `man bash`:

> QUOTING
>
> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.   The  word 
>   expands  to  string,  with  backslash-escaped  characters replaced as
>   specified by the ANSI C standard.  Backslash escape sequences, if
>   present, are decoded as follows:
>
> ```
> (...)
> \n     new line
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use **`echo -e`** or **`printf`** with **`\\n`** for new-line.

Example (with `echo -e`):

```
$ grep -C1 --group-separator="$(echo -e line1\\n\\nline2)" 'hello' a
hello
this is me
line1
line2
something else
hello hello
bye
```

Example (with `printf`):

```
$ grep -C1 --group-separator="$(printf hello\\nfedorqui)" 'hello' a
hello
this is me
hello

fedorqui
something else
hello hello
bye
```

One advantage is we are using **double quote**. (hence variable expansion, etc. work)

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to use `printf` or `echo`. In your case, `grep -C1 --group-separator=$'hello\nfedorqui' 'hello' a` is equivalent.

Comment: @fedorqui yes, let me delete my redundant answer!

Comment: Thanks however for the effort, if I hadn't found the `$''` yours would be the good way to go!

Comment: @fedorqui Btw, I found failure with`$'$var'` (unable to expand/print value of variable if set by single quote!) right? whereas `"$(echo $var)"` can work.

Comment: Yes, this is right. But you can then say `$'"$var"'`. That is `$'` + `"$var"` + `'`.

Comment: @fedorqui [no](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209971/66803) you've end single quote like: `$'sting1'"$var"'$string'`

Comment: You are right, I didn't test properly. `--group-separator=$''"$var"''` works fine and so `--group-separator=$"$var"` does.