# Is there any way to print value inside variable inside single quote?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, variable-substitution

Consider I've set variable `site` and needs to be printed by `echo` or `printf`, but If I use single quote to write something and want to use variable then how?

Example:

```
$ site=unix.stackexchange.com
$ echo "visit:$site"
visit:unix.stackexchange.com
```

But If I use single quote:

```
$ echo 'visit:$site'
visit:$site
```

Then we know that `''` is strong quote and will not expand the variable

I've tried something:

```
$ echo 'visit:"$site"'
visit:"$site"
```

but do not succeed. So, I am looking for *way to print value inside variable while using single quote*.

Comment: Please *show* *the output you want.*

Answer (score 49):

You can't expand variables in single quotes. You can end single quotes and start double quotes, though:

```
echo 'visit:"'"$site"'"'
```

Or, you can backslash double quotes inside of double quotes:

```
echo "visit:\"$site\""
```

Comment: I like the suggestion of replacing single quotes with double quotes, and escaping them when they need to be there literally. For me, this reads more easily than other suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

When you deal with printing variable content, you should stick with [printf instead of echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/38906):

```
printf 'visit:%s\n' "$site"
```

will output `visit:` followed by content of `$site` and a newline regardless of characters in `$site`.

Answer (score 2):

I’m assuming you want the output

```
visit:'unix.stackexchange.com'
```

While [Stephen’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210004/80216) is dangerous, it suggests this approach:

```
$ cat << EOF
> visit:'$site'
> EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your request right, you can eval(uate) the echoed string. E.g.:

```
# eval echo 'visit:$site'
visit:unix.stackexchange.com
```

Comment: It appears that what's asked for is the output `'visit:unix.stackexchange.com'`, with single quotes.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you @drgnfr !  Full demonstration: `cd /var && QUOTED='cd $HOME' && echo $QUOTED && $(eval echo "$QUOTED")` -- first command moves you to a specific dir, at the end you will be in your HOME dir

Answer (score 0):

when concatenating a string and a variable the variable has to be outside of the quotation marks as anything between the quotation marks will be printed literally.

```
echo 'visit:'$site
```

If you wanted to continue the string after the variable you would do the same:

```
echo 'visit: '$site' rest of the sentence'
```

Comment: That's a really bad approach, I'm sad to say. _Always_ double-quote your variables (unless you _really know_ exactly when you don't need to do so) so that the shell doesn't break the values on whitespace. In your example you should have `echo "visit:$site"` rather than `echo 'visit:'$site`, and `echo "visit: '$site' rest of sentence"` instead of `echo 'visit: '$site' rest of the sentence'`. If your fixed text contains a quote or other special character you can either jump in and out of quotes or escape them, eg `echo '"Look out", said '"$person"` or `echo "\"Look out\", said $person"`

Answer (score -1):

choroba is correct.

Though if this were some sort of riddle, I'd respond with this:

```
cat << EOF | sh
> echo 'visit:$site'
> EOF
```

As jander points out this is wide open for an injection attack.  It wasn't a serious answer, so if anyone was considering using something like this, don't use it with untrusted input.  For example, validate the `$site` string as being a valid URL before blindly executing the content.  Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183444/check-for-valid-link-url) could help (but the expression provided isn't perfect because it still allows injection, but use that sort of mechanic to test it).

Comment: I think `EOF` (itself) working as (another) single quote (something like: `bash -c 'echo 'visit:$site''`)!

Comment: I hope `$site` doesn't contain `'\nrm -rf /\necho '`!