# Variable won't get expanded when INSIDE mysql shell

Tags: bash, shell, mysql, variable-substitution, database

Before creating a new mysql user and DB, I did:

```
read sps -s 
    # Inputing and saving the sps (password) value.

echo ${sps}
    # sps password value echoed.

mysql -u root -p[PASSWORD]
    mysql>
        CREATE user "test"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "${sps}";
```

### The problem

When I came to login with `mysql -u test -p[SPS_PASSWORD_VALUE]` I got an error that access has been denied.

The password wasn't the value I gave for `${sps}` but rather `${sps}` itself, **as a string**.

### The catch

To prove "formally" that the problem is due to the `${sps} variable not being expanded **inside** mysql shell, and therefore acts as a regular string, I created another user`test1` providing a password manually (not from a variable) and this time I could login just fine.

### The question

Why when I'm inside the mysql shell, there's no variable expansion and how could I prevent that behavior or at least getting a behavior close to that?

Maybe it's a bug?

Comment: Variable expansion is working in bash (shell), and mysql cli is not bash. This is the expected operation.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209971/is-there-any-way-to-print-value-inside-variable-inside-single-quote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't because the MySQL Shell does not expand environment variables. The Password of user `test` would be `${sps}` literally. But you can let Bash expand the variable and feed the result into MySQL:

```
echo "CREATE user \"test\"@\"localhost\" IDENTIFIED BY \"${sps}\";" | mysql -u root -p[PASSWORD]
```

Comment: Thanks, in the end I used something similar: `echo "CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY \"${sps}\";" | mysql -u root -p"${rps}"`.