# How to execute a command that has many nested single and double quotes with a quoted variable in bash

Tags: bash, quoting, variable, variable-substitution

Here is my simple script

```
#!/bin/sh
thefile=/home/ark/arkserver/ShooterGame/Saved/SaveIsland/1288804998.arktribe

while inotifywait "${thefile}" ; do
    a=\"`strings ${thefile} | tail -n 5 | head -n 1 | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'`\"
echo $a

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{\"username\": \"Island\", \"content\": $a}' https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/5738674701/OjRQiAWHq5mX0Tn2MfBlF-mI41TWrVYVAbOfXpeZWqo8

done
```

Here is the output

```
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
/home/ark/arkserver/ShooterGame/Saved/SaveIsland/1288804998.arktribe ATTRIB
"Day 600, 21:31:17: Phorce1 demolished a 'Campfire'!"
{"code": 50006, "message": "Cannot send an empty message"}Setting up watches.
Watches established.
```

I cannot figure out how to get the curl command properly quoted with the variable inserted in the middle. This is what the command should look like. This works when typed out on the command line

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username": "test", "content": "Day 600, 14:51:00: Phorce1 demolished a 'Campfire'!"}' https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/594723628738674701/OjRQn2MfBlF-FJVl1cWwMlD6UQf0c
```

I have tried many different forms of quoting. The fact that it echos $a as properly quoted but still breaks something in the command that uses it confuses me.

(Yes, I mangled my webhook address)

This question was marked as a duplicate to [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209971/is-there-any-way-to-print-value-inside-variable-inside-single-quote), but the answers to that question were to simply escape the quotes. The "nested quotes" nature of the curl command line in my script causes those answers to fail. I tried many forms of escaping the quotes before posting my own question. Using escaped quotes as mentioned in the answer on the other question I could get a simple "echo" of the variable inside quotes with no problem but inserting that "inside the quotes that were inside other quotes that were inside another set of quotes" in the curl command line would fail.

Comment: @rush Please note the answer I selected here is quite different from the replies to that question. **I tried escaping the quotes around the variable** but the "many nested quotes" nature of he curl command line cause that to fail. So, no, this is not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single quotes **prevent** variable expansion.

I would do this:

```
url=https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/5738674701/OjRQiAWHq5mX0Tn2MfBlF-mI41TWrVYVAbOfXpeZWqo8
while inotifywait "$thefile" ; do
    a=$(strings "$thefile" | tail -n 5 | head -n 1 | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g')
    echo "$a"
    payload=$(printf '{"username": "Island", "content": "%s"}' "$a")
    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "$payload" "$url" 
done
```

You don't need to escape double quotes inside of single quotes. In fact, if you do, the escape will be preserved as a literal character.

Always quote your variables, unless you know exactly what might happen if you don't.

(This is a matter of personal style) You don't *need* to brace a variable inside of quotes, unless you need to disambiguate the variable name from surrounding text:

```
echo "$aVariable"
echo "${aVariable}_abc"
```

Comment: Thank you. I write little scripts so seldom I had to go look up a refresher on printf to figure out what the %s was doing. I was also looking at other similar questions that suggested creating a function for the curl command but this, fixing my quoting using variables, feels more right to me.

Answer (score 0):

To create a JSON document containing user-provided data, and correctly encode it etc., use something like `jq`:

```
payload=$( jq --arg content "$data" -n '{"username": "Island", "content": $content}' )
```

This would create a small JSON document in `$payload` that contains the value of `$data` in in the value field of the `content` key.  The value will be properly quoted (things like double quotes and non-ASCII characters will be handled correctly).

For example, if `$data` is, literally

```
"hello
world"
```

(including quotes and newline), the command above would create the following JSON document and assign it to tho `payload` variable:

```
{
  "username": "Island",
  "content": "\"hello\nworld\""
}
```

To delete useless whitespace in the generated document, use `jq` with its `-c` option.

The full script would look like

```sh
#!/bin/sh

url='https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/5738674701/OjRQiAWHq5mX0Tn2MfBlF-mI41TWrVYVAbOfXpeZWqo8'
file='/home/ark/arkserver/ShooterGame/Saved/SaveIsland/1288804998.arktribe'

while inotifywait "$file" ; do
    data=$( strings "$file" | tail -n 5 | head -n 1 | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' )
    payload=$( jq --arg content "$data" -n '{"username": "Island", "content": $content}' )

    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
         -X POST \
         -d "$payload" \
         "$url"
done
```

The only quoting you need to worry about is of the shell variables, which should be double quoted [as usual](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary).  There is no need to try to insert literal quotes into the data read from your pipeline.