# How to insert comment at specific variable line number by sed command?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to comment out a line (add a `#` to the beginning). I used this command: `sed -i '96s/^/#&/' file.txt` on Linux to insert comment at line # 96.

If the line number is a variable, then how can I use this command? 
I have tried these commands:

(1)

```
sed -i '${line_number}s|^|#&|' file.txt
```

(2)

```
sed -i '${line_number}s/^/#&/' file.txt
```

But they don't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Variables are [not expanded](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209971/is-there-any-way-to-print-value-inside-variable-inside-single-quote) when using single quotes. Use double quotes instead:

```
 sed -i "${line_number}"'s/^/#/' file.txt
```

You don't need the `&`. It means insert whole match, which is empty.