# Import variable into jq

Tags: shell-script, json, jq

We need to use the variable `$domain_name` instead of the `hyb.com` string in the following `jq` command:

```
jq --argjson IDS '['"$(seq -s, -f'"car%02.0f_hyb.com"' 11)"']' '
  .mazda |= $IDS
' file.json
```

When we just set the variable as

```
export domain_name=_hyb.com

jq --argjson IDS '['"$(seq -s, -f'"car%02.0f$domain_name "' 11)"']' '
  .mazda |= $IDS
' file.json
```

Then the exported variable `domain_name` is not see by `jq`.  Are there any suggestion of how to import the variable into `jq`?

Comment: You put `"car%02.0f$domain_name "` in single quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to print value inside variable inside single quote?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209971/is-there-any-way-to-print-value-inside-variable-inside-single-quote): `echo '{"mazda": []}' | jq --argjson IDS '['"$(seq -s, -f'"car%02.0f'"$domain_name"'"' 11)"']' '.mazda |= $IDS'` => `{
  "mazda": [
    "car01_hyb.com",
    "car02_hyb.com",
    "car03_hyb.com",
    "car04_hyb.com",
    "car05_hyb.com",
    "car06_hyb.com",
    "car07_hyb.com",
    "car08_hyb.com",
    "car09_hyb.com",
    "car10_hyb.com",
    "car11_hyb.com"
  ]
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `$domain_name` in single quotes. This is why the shell is not expanding the variable.

In this case, though, I would suggest doing it a slightly different way:

`jq` provides safe ways to import raw data from the shell:

```
jq '.mazda |= $ARGS.positional' file.json --args car{00..11}"$domain_name"
```

This would insert the `mazda` key with the values taken from the list after `--args` on the command line.  The `--args` and the list of values should be last on the command line. The values will be JSON-encoded as by `jq` if needs be. This is usually better than trying to create correct JSON yourself from data that may come from external sources (for example, if the data that you want to insert contains tabs or newlines or double quotes, `jq` will encode these properly as JSON strings with `--args`).

The list is generated using a brace expansion. Assuming you are using `bash` release 4 or later, the numbers generated by `{00..11}` would be properly zero-filled.

Note that `domain_name` does not need to be an environment (exported) variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think your main issue is that you don't use the variable in the input to `jq` - you use it as the input to `seq`.

That being said, @muru's comment is correct, as well as pointing to the question ["Is there any way to print value inside variable inside single quote?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209971/4323) - which you've already demonstrated that you know how to use: you have used it in escaping the output of `seq` into the `jq` argument.

But your problem can be solved in a much easier way, because you don't actually need to use a single quote in the `seq` input: you only think you do because you want to use double quotes in the input value, but you can easily escape those:

```bsh
seq -s, -f "\"car%02.0f${domain_name}\"" 11
```